# React custom element is in DOM, but not visible

Tags: html, reactjs

I am trying to create an element in React, but I cannot get it to be visible. It shows up in the Elements tab of the Chrome developer console, but when I hover over it there it doesn't even show a location. I have other custom elements that work fine, it is this in particular that is not rendering. Here is the code defining the element:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDom from "react-dom";

const Modal = (props) => {
    const [domReady, setDomReady] = React.useState(false)

    React.useEffect(() => {
        setDomReady(true)
    })

    return domReady?ReactDom.createPortal(
        <>
            <div className="modal">
                TEST
            </div>
            <div onClick={() => {}} className="backdrop">

            </div>
        </>,
        document.getElementById('modal-root')
    ):null
}

export default Modal;
```

Here is the CSS that affects it, though it is worth noting that even without this CSS I see nothing:

```
.modal {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    width: 30rem;
    z-index: 10;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
  
  .backdrop {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
```

Edit: Here is the file which uses the component:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

//import Loading from '../Loading/Loading';
import './Income.css';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import IncomeRow from '../../components/IncomeRow/IncomeRow';
import Button from '../../components/Button/Button';
import Modal from '../../components/Modal/Modal';

const Income = () => {

    //Initializing
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    // modal visibility states
    const [editModalVisible, setEditModalVisibility] = useState(false);
    const [deleteModalVisible, setDeleteModalVisibility] = useState(false);
    const [addModalVisible, setAddModalVisibility] = useState(false);

    // show modal to edit income
    const onEditClick = () => {
        setEditModalVisibility(true);
    }
    const onDismissEditModal = () => {
        setEditModalVisibility(false);
    }

    //returning JSX
    return (
        <>
            <div className='Incomes'>
                {/* TODO: make these autogenerate from database */}
                <IncomeRow name="income 1" source="Company 1" date="1/1/2022" amount={123.45} id="1" editFunction={onEditClick}/>
                <IncomeRow name="income 2" source="Company 2" date="7/31/2022" amount={420.69} id="2"editFunction={onEditClick}/>
            </div>
            <Button text="Add Income"/>
            <Modal dismissModal={onDismissEditModal}/>
        </>
        );
}

export default Income
```

Here is App.js, which holds the base of the layout:

```
import React, { useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar/Navbar';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
//import { ThemeContext, themes } from './context/themeContext';
import { Outlet, useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar/>
      <div className='body'>
          <div id='modal-root'>
            <Outlet/>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Show us the `index.html` file

Comment: @kinduser there isn't an index.html, but I added the app.js which is the equivalent I believe.

Comment: You are not calling the Modal component anywhere in this code, do you have it on your routes file?

Comment: @Hamlet I pasted the wrong code in before because I wasn't thinking. Now you can see the page that uses it.

Comment: I need your file where you have the native HTML code with root

Comment: @kinduser added that. I apologize for misunderstanding